# How to select the entire row in R instead of just the first element?

Tags: r, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to collect an entire array of data (hours 0, 3, 6...48). My code currently only collects hh = 0 because the "name" of the row has a comma in it.

The data in tempjson$score_value is structured as follows:

```
tempjson$score_value
         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]     [,7]     [,8]
[1,] 3.492809 2.962649 2.770052 2.756788 2.332905 2.338647 2.719658 3.080747
[2,] 3.558785 3.581791 3.475497 3.451713 3.009123 3.104995 3.397145 3.781619
```

etc.

I am trying to plot the score value for each hour (each column) for both experiments (both rows).

```
tempjson$score_value[1]
[1] 3.492809
```

only selects the very first element, but

```
> tempjson$score_value[1,]
 [1] 3.492809 2.962649 2.770052 2.756788 2.332905 2.338647 2.719658 3.080747
3.406330 3.281600 3.028505 2.976836 2.575598 2.421316 2.894790 3.132405
3.541107
```

provides the entire row. 
My code is a for loop that tries to compile a tempscore array of all the hours' values for both experiments [2x17]:

```
 for(exp in seq(1,length(expname)))
      for(hh in tempjson$label[[exp]])
           tempscore[exp,which(list.runhour==hh)]=tempjson$score_value[[exp]][which(tempjson$label[[exp]]==hh)]
```

where:

```
> expname
[1] "experiment1"  "experiment2"
```

and

```
> list.runhour
 [1] "0"  "3"  "6"  "9"  "12" "15" "18" "21" "24" "27" "30" "33" "36" "39" "42"
[16] "45" "48"
```

and

```
> tempjson$label
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14]
[1,] "0"  "3"  "6"  "9"  "12" "15" "18" "21" "24" "27"  "30"  "33"  "36"  "39"
[2,] "0"  "3"  "6"  "9"  "12" "15" "18" "21" "24" "27"  "30"  "33"  "36"  "39"
     [,15] [,16] [,17]
[1,] "42"  "45"  "48"
[2,] "42"  "45"  "48"
```

and

```
> tempjson$score_value
         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]     [,7]     [,8]
[1,] 3.492809 2.962649 2.770052 2.756788 2.332905 2.338647 2.719658 3.080747
[2,] 3.558785 3.581791 3.475497 3.451713 3.009123 3.104995 3.397145 3.781619
         [,9]   [,10]    [,11]    [,12]    [,13]    [,14]    [,15]    [,16]
[1,] 3.406330 3.28160 3.028505 2.976836 2.575598 2.421316 2.894790 3.132405
[2,] 4.163044 3.89846 3.626449 3.615926 3.260005 3.190443 3.648776 3.873211
        [,17]
[1,] 3.541107
[2,] 4.256343
```

Running this code results, from line 1, in exp = [1] and not [1,]. As such, hh only ever = "0" and not the other 16 values [1x17 array from 0 to 48].

How do I get exp to equal the name of the row, i.e., [1,], so that the for loop correctly calls all the columns (hhs)?

Comment: What tis the the `tempscore` object?  Is that a `matrix`?

Comment: Can you please edit your post with the `dput` of all the examples and the correct `for` loop that is reproducible for that small example

Comment: You showed the `dput` of `tempjson$score_value` as a matrix, while you are subsetting it with `[[` `tempjson$score_value[[exp]]`  If you are subsetting the rows, ti would be `tempjson$score_value[exp, , drop = FALSE]` but not clear without the correct flow of code

Comment: As I mentioned  in the comments, a complete reproducible example would be more useful, otherwise, we will be doing the same guesswork

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the `,` to separate the row index from the column index. With `matrix`, if we use only a single index 'n', it will extract the 'n'th element as `matrix` is a `vector` with `dim` attributes

```
tempjson$score_value[1, , drop = FALSE]
```

Here, the `drop = FALSE` is used to avoid the matrix dropping the dimensions when the number of rows or columns is 1.  It is explained in `?Extract`

Comment: Thanks but that command doesn't seem to work. Are you suggesting I change the tempscore line in my code to this:
     'tempscore[exp,which(list.runhour==hh)]=tempjson$score_value[[exp], , drop=FALSE][which(tempjson$label[[exp]]==hh)]'

It returns the following error: Error in tempjson$score_value[[exp]] : invalid subscript type 'builtin'

Comment: @zemone  My  code is based on the output you showed `tempjson$score_value`  It is a matrix and you can get the entire row of a matrix by specifying the row index followed by the `,`. The `drop = FALSE` is to avoid  coercing to vector

Comment: OK, how would I call that functionality given my current code line? Currently it won't let me input a ,

Comment: @zemone  Can you please update with the `dput` of the example as I can't understand the structure correctly

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? 
Apologies, I'm new to R and don't know what the dput command is for.

Comment: @zemone  It is a function that gives the structure of the exact dataset you are working on so that others can reproduce it.  If you use a small example `dput(head(iris))` it gives the first 6 rows strcutre, which you can copy/paste and sent it to others to work on. Similarly, in your example, it is a bit complicated

Comment: OK, this is the result:  
     dput(tempjson$score_value)
structure(c(-3.4752, -3.4509, 0.9393, 0.5789, -2.7983, -1.9936,
3.3343, 3.5876), .Dim = c(2L, 4L))

Comment: @zemone It looks like a `matrix` and `m1[1, , drop = FALSE]#
        [,1]   [,2]    [,3]   [,4]
[1,] -3.4752 0.9393 -2.7983 3.3343` gives the first row

Comment: NVM this is the result here: 
OK, this is the result:  
dput(tempjson$score_value)
structure(c(3.49280887096774, 3.55878548387097, 2.96264893617021,
3.5817911, 2.77005197, 3.47549, 2.7567875,
3.45171, 2.3329015, 3.00912291, 2.33864673913043,
3.1049949, 2.7196581, 3.39714476534296, 3.0803,
3.78161908127208, 3.40632964285714, 4.16304428571429, 3.2816,
3.89845971731449, 3.02850535714286, 3.62644928571429, 2.97683581560284,
3.61592624113475, 2.57559785714286, 3.260005, 2.42131588447653,
3.19044, 2.8947, 3.64877625, 3.132405,
3.873210, 3.541106, 4.256343), .Dim = c(2L,
17L))

Comment: OK how do I call that in my for for loops where tempscore[exp,which(list.runhour==hh)]= .....

Comment: @zemone The `tempjson$score_value` is a matrix with 2 rows and 17 columns (based on the dput).  What is `exp` and what is `list.runhour`

Comment: exp is either "1" or "2", as it's called in the for loop (length of expname = 2)
list.runhour = 0, 3, 6, ... 48, as provided in my initial post. Hope that helps?